# Different expressions for multivalued logarithm

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

> I am trying to solve $ \cosh(z)=-5, \  \forall z\in\mathbb{C}$.

My attempt:

\begin{align}
\cosh(z)&=-5 \\
\frac{e^z+e^{-z}}{2}&=-5 \\
(e^z)^2+10e^z+1&=0 \\
e^z&=\frac{-10+ \sqrt{96}}{2} \\
 e^z&=-5+ \sqrt{6} \\
\implies z&=\pm\log(-5+2\sqrt{6}) \ \ \ \text{(log is mulitvalued)}
\end{align}

The answer provided is $$\pm\log(5+2\sqrt{6})+(2k+1)\pi i \ \ k\in\mathbb{Z}$$
My questions is, how is

> $$\pm\log(-5+2\sqrt{6}) \equiv\pm\log(5+2\sqrt{6})+(2k+1)\pi i \ \ k\in\mathbb{Z} \ \ \text{(where log is mulitvalued)}$$

Comment: You may not have noticed that $$5+2\sqrt6=-{1\over-5+2\sqrt6}$$

Comment: Could I use the fact that $-5+2\sqrt{6}<0$ and hence the argument is $(2k+1)\pi i,  \  k\in\mathbb{Z}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $-5 \pm \sqrt 6$ is a real number so Arg$( -5 \pm \sqrt 6 )=0$

Comment: I'm not sure where the $\pm$ sign outside of Log comes from. Also, why were the $PV$ removed? I think they were valid, as $\pm PV\sqrt{2}\neq \pm\sqrt{2}$. It should be that $\pm PV\sqrt{2}=+\sqrt{2}$ if the you wish to remove the $PV$.

Comment: I am not familiar with the $\pm PV $ notation. If you meant the positive value, why not just keep the $+$ sign?

Comment: My lecturer uses them interchangeably. I will edit now.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Please edit as you wish.

Comment: I have edited the question. I am unsure of how the answer is obtained.

Comment: Use the definition of logarithm and note that -log (z)=log(1/z) where $z=-5+2\sqrt 6$